# Как передать текст из переменной в буфер обмена (скопировать определенный текст)(С++)

Tags: c++

Нужна функция которая передаст текст из переменной (string) в буфер обмена

Comment: Зависит от ОС. Windows?

Comment: да windows, седьмой.

Comment: `SetClipboardData()` - [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264137/how-to-copy-string-to-clipboard-in-c) есть примеры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Тут](http://netcode.ru/cpp/?lang=&katID=3&skatID=22&artID=248) должно быть описано все что надо

Строка, которую я посчитал нужной:

```
SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, bm.m_hObject);
```